# $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{(2k)!!}{n \choose k}{2^{n-k}}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am unable to solve this exercise:

> Find a solution in a closed form of: 
>   $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{(2k)!!}{n \choose k}{2^{n-k}}.$$

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{k!}{2^k\cdot k!}\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k} = 2^n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{4^k} = \color{red}{2^n\cdot\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)^n-1\right)}.$$